# Including inline Custom Fields info with add_filter in functions.php

Tags: custom-field, functions, filters

I have a function set up to place some standard text in each post for a Custom Post Type. However, within that standard text I want to pull some unique text from a few custom fields. Not sure what is wrong with my code:

```
function default_content($content) {
  global $post;
  if ($post->post_type == 'my-custom-post-type') {
    $content .= '<p style="text-align: center;"><strong>Custom Field Text here: <?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), \'custom-field-1\', true )</strong></p>
    <p style="text-align: center;"><a href="http://myblog.com/?checkout=<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), \'custom-field-2\', true )">Link 01</a></p>';
  }
  return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'default_content', 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to echo within a variable. You also have encapsulated PHP tags in the string as well. You need to concatenate just the functions themselves like this:

```
    function default_content($content) {
        global $post;

        if ($post->post_type == 'my-custom-post-type') {
            $content .= '<p style="text-align: center;"><strong>Custom Field Text here: '. get_post_meta( $post->ID, "custom-field-1", true ).'</strong></p>
                         <p style="text-align: center;"><a href="http://myblog.com/?checkout=' . get_post_meta( $post->ID, "custom-field-2", true ).'">Link 01</a></p>';
        }
        return $content;
    }
    add_filter('the_content', 'default_content', 0);
```

Also you are calling global $post, so use $post->ID instead of get_the_ID().

Cheers!

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I am slowly but surely getting the hang of this WordPress thing (I think)! Much appreciated on the help.

Comment: No worries. :) That's why we're here. Everyone has to start somewhere.